# How would you implement routing within an Activity for AppLinks?

Tags: android, applinks

So the [applinks](http://applinks.org/documentation/) documentation states that you should specify your app's package name through the `al:android:package` property, and the consuming application should launch an Intent to start your app. What I feel is lacking from the documentation is a suggestion or specification on how to provide custom parameters or routing info with that Intent. It's not *deep linking* unless you specify some depth!

It does specify how to provide Extras through the use of the `al_applink_data` structure. It does not however say how the target application should provide metadata for the client to consume and send with that structure.

The only suggestion I can think of is to provide the metadata through the optional `al:android:url`-parameter. So for instance if I'm running a blog, I would provide the URL `com.myblog://123`, "123" being the ID to a blog entry.

I don't feel like this is an optimal solution. I would then have to parse the URL in order to get the argument. I feel a better solution would be to have a an applink-property named something like `al:android:extras` where I could give key-value pairs to consume directly. Why is it not implemented this way?

Am I doing it right if I implement metadata-passing the way I described? Is there something I'm missing with regards to the applinks spec?

Comment: The original http(s) url is give to you inside al_applink_data under the target_url key, so you can certainly pass metadata that way. Passing it via the optional al:android:url is also OK, and lastly, if you have cooperation from the calling app, they can certainly pass data to you via the extras blob. The reason there's no al:android:extras is that app links was designed to be a routing protocol, and not describe semantics for your app.

Comment: Fair enough. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original http(s) url is given to you inside al_applink_data under the target_url key, so you can certainly pass metadata that way.

Passing it via the optional al:android:url is also OK.

Lastly, if you have cooperation from the calling app, they can certainly pass data to you via the extras blob.

The reason there's no al:android:extras is that app links was designed to be a routing protocol, and not describe semantics for your app.